# How to create and call a JavaScript function that accepts three parameters (length of the page) and calculates the area of the block

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to write function that accepts 3 parameters and then returns area of the block. I've working on this for few days and I don't have answers. I need some help.

Comment: You should probably bring over your example code from the other question.

Comment: I am from Bosnia, so some of the words maybe you wouldn't understand, but here is a html :

Comment: Put it in your question.

Comment: Can't ... something went wrong. I dont know what's happening, im new in this

Comment: I trying and trying but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// We declare the function 
var areaOfBlock = function(a,b,c) {
  // we tell it to return to us what it gets
  // when it multiplies a by b and then that answer
  // by c

  // could also be written like:
  // var area = a * b *c;
  // return area;

    return a * b * c;
}
```